# Making Meteor ddp call unblock

Tags: meteor

This Meteor server code tries to use this.unblock() before each of the ddp calls in order not to block the code and continue to the next lines. but it it giving the error:

> Exception in callback of async function: TypeError: _this.unblock is not a function

```
connection1 = DDP.connect('http://localhost:3000');
myFunc = (function () {
   this.unblock();
   connection1.call('methodOnDDP1', arg1);
   this.unblock();
   connection1.call('methodOnDDP2', arg1);
}());
```

Any idea how to make those ddp calls unblock? thx

Comment: `unblock` is for the method handler, not the method caller.

Comment: Are you implying to use it on the method handler in order to make the ddp unblock? and if so, how?

Comment: I'm not implying, I am stating it clearly. You are trying to use `unblock` on a ddp connection, which obviously does not have an `unblock()` method. You need to call `this.unblock()` in the method body itself (the methods that go into the `Meteor.methods` call on the server), as `unblock` is related to the meteor method context.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for that. If callback is used `connection1.call('methodOnDDP1', arg1, function (){})`, would that also give the same "unblock" effect?

Comment: The methods are called immediately one after the other from the client. The server handler decides whether or not to block. The callback does not affect the way stuff is handled. If you want to method not to block on the server, you need to change the server code.